# Is there a more efficient way to set variables on a RadioButton's CheckChanged event?

Tags: windows, events, forms, radio-button

I have 16 radio buttons in an application of mine..
I have to set a variable based on which one was selected.. and I've produced some very ugly code doing this..

```
private void Foo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        convertSource = 1;
    }

private void Bar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        convertSource = 2;
    }

private void Baz_RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        convertSource = 3;
    }
```

Now, I've been thinking about it and to be honest I thought there might have been a way to do it with a switch.. I just can't conceptualize it in my mind.

If anyone could show me a more efficient way of doing this, I'd really appreciate it.
It's just really bugging me that such a simple thing as this is taking up fifty to seventy lines of code.

thanks,
cpatton

Comment: By a more efficient method, do you mean something that is simpler / cleaner / less code? If by efficiency you mean runtime performance, I doubt it can be much faster than what you're already doing.

Comment: I think he means efficiency in terms of how long it takes to write it, not how fast it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I hate radio buttons if there are more than 2 or 3 choices - a `ComboBox` is a better control for picking one option from many.

However, a quick fix to your problem is to put the convertSource value of each radio button into that control's `Tag` property (do this in the designer).  Add this method to your form:

```
private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    convertSource = (int)((RadioButton)sender).Tag;
}
```

In your form's load event (assuming these radio buttons are all on a group box), assign the handler like this:

```
foreach (RadioButton rb in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChange;
}
```

Make sure you remove all the event handlers that you added manually (like `Foo_CheckedChanged`).

Comment: Ah, thank you! I don't know why I decided to use a radiobutton for this certain task.. a combo box makes so much more sense, so I think i'll go with that.

thank you, i really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the same handler to more than one event. You can write one handler and check which is the sender:

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == Foo_RadioButton) {
        convertSource = 1;
    } else if (sender == Bar_RadioButton) {
        convertSource = 2;
    } else if (sender == Baz_RadioButton) {
        convertSource = 3;
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

or even more concisely:

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton> {
        Foo_RadioButton,
        Bar_RadioButton,
        Baz_RadioButton
    };

    int index = radioButton.IndexOf((RadioButton)sender);
    convertSource = index + 1;
}
```

You can bind this handler to the CheckedChanged event in the properties window for each radio button.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I'm going to actually go with a combobox for this part of my app as it makes a lot more sense.. I hadn't thought about using just one handler and checking the sender, though. That's a great idea, and I appreciate it tons. Will probably use it for another section of my app :)